# Using find to move all files in folder while both keeping source folder structure intact & ignoring files in particular folder

Tags: android, linux, bash, shell, termux

## Aim

To move everything under `/sdcard/Pictures` to `/sdcard/Sync` (using automatic renaming for filename collisions) *except* the contents of `/sdcard/Pictures/.thumbnails/`, which I want left alone.

## Code I have so far

`find /sdcard/Pictures -type f ! -path /sdcard/Pictures/.thumbnails/* -exec mv --backup=numbered {} /sdcard/Sync ';'`

## Error message I'm getting

```
find: paths must precede expression: `/sdcard/Pictures/.thumbnails/210.jpg'
find: possible unquoted pattern after predicate `-path'?
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The unquoted `/sdcard/Pictures/.thumbnails/*` expands to multiple strings *before* `find` gets to see it; the first one will be used as the argument to `-path`, and the second one triggers the error message. Single quote like `'/sdcard/Pictures/.thumbnails/*'` to avoid that. (That's exactly what "possible unquoted pattern after predicate `path'" alludes to.)

Answer (score 0):

Fixed ultimately by deleting the folder I wanted to exclude, as I wasn't interested in it in the 1st place.